# ORA-01735 Primary key and Foreign Key

Tags: foreign-keys, primary-key, ora-01735

> Alter table residential add constraint pk_restype primary key (customerID) REFERENCES customer(customerID);

I'd like to set primary key constraints on 'residential' table but ORA-01735 error appears indicating "invalid ALTER TABLE option". I've also tried the following to make foreign key relation but it also comes up as the same error code.

> Alter table residential add constraint fk_restype foreign key (customerID, customertype) REFERENCES customer(customerID, customertype);

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are creating a primary key as if it is a foreign key.

The proper PK syntax is:

```
alter table residential add constraint pk_restype primary key (customerID);
```

No references clause is allowed in a Primary Key, on a Foreign Key.

The PK says this column `customerID` is unique and identifies a unique row in the `residential` table. It has nothing to do with referencing another table.

A FK would be:

```
alter table tab_child add constraint fk_child FOREIGN key (child_id)
   REFERENCES tab_parent(id);
```

The FK says a column `child_id` in table `tab_child` refers to and is constrained by the column `id` in table `tab_parent`

Comment: The primary key works but the foreign key syntax you've suggested comes up as ORA-02298 "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found" - an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has child records. eventhough the PK for the parent key has already been set,

Comment: That is the point of a foreign key. You quoted part of the error, but left off the most important part of it, `ORA-2298` is `parent keys not found`. You have child records with values that aren't represented in the parent table, for the key column. Don't you understand what a foreign key is? The child record must have a parent record. By default, you cant enable a foreign key on data that isn't valid for the constraint. Fix the data first.